# How to recover deleted gmail emails?

Tags: email-server, email, gmail, hacking

Is there a program to recover emails that I deleted in my gmail account? I've already checked the "trash" and they are gone.Please help me.

Comment: You might get better answers for this here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no. No Backup, no restore.
You could try to contact google for that, but i don't there is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but if you've previously enabled Offline Mail for the gmail account on a different computer, then you could power on that computer without connecting to the internet and it would have the emails from the last time you turned it on.